# How to save state of toggleClass method using jquery cookie plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am aware of similar questions which I have looked at but the answers haven't worked for me yet.

So I am trying to save the state of the JavaScript toggleClass method so that when the user refreshes the page it loads the saved state. At the moment it just reverts back to original state as it normally would. I am trying to do this using the jquery cookie plugin https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

My code is as followed

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".steps").click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("selected");
   $.cookie("selected", $(this).hasClass("selected"));
  });
});
```

Nothing is showing up amiss in console so I'm stumped for answers.

Comment: Well that code sets the cookie, where do you read it back and toggle?

Comment: I don't, I have tried placing $.cookie("selected"); straight after but it still doesn't save. Am I reading the cookie in the right place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the boolean is set. You store a string but need a boolean

[*JSFIDDLE*](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/7ooox3cj/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var sel = $.cookie("selected"); // get the cookie
   sel = sel=="true"; // convert to boolean - null is false, "false" is false
   $(".steps").toggleClass("selected",sel); // initial
   $(".steps").on("click",function() {
     var $this = $(this);
     sel = !sel; // toggle
     $this.toggleClass("selected",sel); // toggles
     $.cookie("selected", sel,{ expires: 7, path: '/' });
  });
});
```

Comment: Interesting, you are right it does the opposite, it seems to toggle the state to "selected" automatically when loading the page.

Comment: Still seems to do the same thing

Comment: Updated to get a boolean from the cookie

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if($.cookie("selected")){
    $(".steps").addClass("selected");
} 

   $(".steps").click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("selected");
   $.cookie("selected", $(this).hasClass("selected"));
  });
});
```

Comment: This also seems to toggle the state to "selected" automatically when loading the page. Change of state isn't saving either.